# ModuleLoadException when Thread.CurrentPrincipal is set with a principal containing a custom IIdentity

Tags: c++, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, com, asp.net-web-api

We have an application hosted in ASP.NET MVC WebAPI, which uses an external managed library. This managed library again uses a COM library. The COM library is a general purpose library used by many applications and in different versions, so we want to be able to to run it side-by-side by loading it directly from the bin folder and not not use the traditional COM registration. We have achieved this by adding a manifest file and making a call to CreateActCtx in kernel32.dll to register a custom activation context (code is included below).

This is working fine by itself, however when we set Thread.CurrentPrincipal to a GenericPrincipal instance with a custom IIdentity implementation before the COM library is loaded, we get a <CrtImplementationDetails>.ModuleLoadException with the message "The C++ module failed to load while attempting to initialize the default appdomain.". It has an inner System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException saying it cannot load the assembly which actually initiated the load of the COM assembly in the first place. The stacktrace is:

```
Server stack trace: 
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage.FixupForNewAppDomain()
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoDispatch(Byte[] reqStmBuff, SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMcm, SmuggledMethodReturnMessage& smuggledMrm)
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatchCallback(Object[] args)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
    at System.AppDomain.get_Id()
    at <CrtImplementationDetails>.DoCallBackInDefaultDomain(IntPtr function, Void* cookie)
    at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport._Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
    at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
    at .cctor()
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

When we do not set Thread.CurrentPrincipal or use a GenericPrincipal with a GenericIdentity inside it works fine. For now the solution with a GenericIdentity is the workaround for us, because we are mainly setting Thread.CurrentPrincipal to take use of ASP.NET MVC authentication.

The following code works:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("bla"), new string[0]);
```

...while the following doesn't:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new CustomIdentity("bla"), new string[0]);
```

The following is the global.asax code being used to register the custom activation context referencing the bin folder and the manifest file to do reg-free COM:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private const UInt32 ERROR_SXS_PROCESS_DEFAULT_ALREADY_SET = 14011;
    IntPtr hActCtx;
    private static readonly ILogger s_logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Required files are copied in host projects post-build event
        // NB! you can only set the default activation context like this once per app domain,
        //  so if you need multiple apps/services using side-by-side they cannot share app pool.

        UInt32 dwError = 0;
        string binDirectory = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"bin");
        string manifestPath = Path.Combine(binDirectory, "Iit.OpenApi.Services.ReferenceData.manifest");
        var activationContext = new ACTCTX();
        activationContext.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ACTCTX));
        activationContext.dwFlags = ACTCTX_FLAG_SET_PROCESS_DEFAULT | ACTCTX_FLAG_ASSEMBLY_DIRECTORY_VALID;
        activationContext.lpSource = manifestPath;
        activationContext.lpAssemblyDirectory = binDirectory;
        hActCtx = CreateActCtx(ref activationContext);
        if (hActCtx.ToInt32() == -1)
        {
            dwError = (UInt32)Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }

        if ((hActCtx.ToInt32() == -1) && (dwError != Global.ERROR_SXS_PROCESS_DEFAULT_ALREADY_SET))
        {
            var err = string.Format("Cannot create process-default win32 sxs context, error={0} manifest={1}", dwError, manifestPath);
            throw new ApplicationException(err);
        }
        // TODO: add eventid to enum
        if ((hActCtx.ToInt32() == -1) && (dwError == Global.ERROR_SXS_PROCESS_DEFAULT_ALREADY_SET))
        {
            GetCurrentActCtx(out hActCtx);
            s_logger.Info(9998, string.Format("Re-using exising ActivationContext [{0}].", hActCtx.ToInt64()));
        }
        else
        {
            s_logger.Info(9998, string.Format("ActivationContext [{0}] created successfully.", hActCtx.ToInt64()));
        }

    }

    protected void Application_End()
    {
        if (hActCtx.ToInt64() != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            ReleaseActCtx(hActCtx);
            // TODO: add eventid to enum
            s_logger.Info(9999, string.Format("ActivationContext [{0}] released successfully.", hActCtx.ToInt64()));
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct ACTCTX
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public string lpSource;
        public ushort wProcessorArchitecture;
        public ushort wLangId;
        public string lpAssemblyDirectory;
        public string lpResourceName;
        public string lpApplicationName;
    }

    private const uint ACTCTX_FLAG_ASSEMBLY_DIRECTORY_VALID = 0x004;
    private const uint ACTCTX_FLAG_SET_PROCESS_DEFAULT = 0x010;
    private const Int64 INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateActCtx(ref ACTCTX actctx);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool GetCurrentActCtx(out IntPtr hActCtx);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern void ReleaseActCtx(IntPtr hActCtx);

}
```

Any input to what is going wrong when using a custom IIdentity, and how I can make it work with reg-free COM?